# how to take output from second table by joining in SQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql

```
table 1                              table 2

id  Name  value                    id  status
1  a      1000                     1   open
2  b      2000                     2   closed
3  c      3000                     3   closed
4  d      4000                     4   open
5  e      5000                     5   open
```

I want the output as the names which are closed. What will be the possible solutions?

Comment: Please post table scripts, sample data and expected output. See http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ for guidance.

Comment: @spaghettidba - excellent page on formatting correctly! Bookmarked!

Comment: This may be a simple question, but that's  not a reason to close it. People weren't born knowing SQL!

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like if you wish to use joins :

```
 select name from table1 t1 inner join table2 t1 on t1.id=t2.id where t2.status = 'closed';
```

or

```
select name from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.status = 'closed';
```